# Where Exists SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested

I have the following statement which gets clients over the age of 80

```
SELECT
    C.ClientID, 
    C.surname  + C.forename As Name,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),  C.DateOfBirth, 103) AS DOB,
    S.SchemeID,
    [Status]
FROM 
    vClients C
INNER JOIN
    vClientSchemes S ON C.ClientID = S.ClientID
INNER JOIN
    vEvents E ON C.ClientId = E.ClientID
WHERE
    (DATEDIFF(yy, C.DateOfBirth, GetDate()) - 
       CASE WHEN((MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(C.DateOfBirth)) >   (MONTH(GetDate()) * 100 + DAY(GetDate()))) 
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 80
    AND (DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GetDate()) - 
        CASE WHEN((MONTH(DateOfBirth) * 100 + DAY(C.DateOfBirth)) >      
                   (MONTH(GetDate()) * 100 + DAY(GetDate()))) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 100
    AND C.[Status] = 0 
    AND S.SchemeID = 3
```

However from the result I also need to get the date of when they were last used by the service.  This is achieved by querying the table with the following columns

```
EventId, EventDate, ClientID
```

So from the events date using the following query.  So far I have

```
SELECT ClientID 
FROM vEvents 
WHERE EventDate > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

But I cant seem to link the two queries

Comment: Your query already includes the vEvents table, so why can't you just add the required columns to the SELECT and add the condition to the WHERE? I'm not understanding where the problem is.

Comment: you could just add `Max(E.EventDate)` to you select and add a `Group By` for the other fields

Comment: If i add the required columns to the select the events table returns multiple  clients id as there are multiple events for each client

Comment: For example without the events I get 727 rows for all clients that have been used since the service started.  If i add the condition to the where clause and use distinct i get 2572 rows - in other words it should be less than the 727

Answer (score 1):

Your where predicates are nonSARGable because you have wrapped your columns in functions. You could make this SARGable AND a lot simpler like this.

```
WHERE DateOfBirth < DATEADD(Year, -80, cast(getdate() as date)
AND DateOfBirth > DATEADD(Year, -100, cast(getdate() as date)
AND C.[Status] = 0 
AND S.SchemeID = 3
```

For your actual question you could use MAX(EventDate) and group by the rest of the columns, or you could use ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have access to the `vEvents` table in your query through alias `E`. You should be able to add the filter you indicated by adding:

```
AND E.EventDate > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

The `ClientID` should be the same from the `vEvents` table as it is from your `vClients` table, due to the inner join, and you're already selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep marc_2 you were right just needed to add the condition and a distinct as well, but remove the select on the EventDate

```
SELECT
distinct C.ClientID, 
C.surname  + C.forename As Name,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),  C.DateOfBirth, 103) AS DOB
FROM vClients C
inner join vClientSchemes S on C.ClientID = S.ClientID
inner join vEvents E ON C.ClientId = E.ClientID
WHERE
(DATEDIFF(yy,C.DateOfBirth,GetDate()) - 
CASE WHEN((MONTH(DateOfBirth)*100 + DAY(C.DateOfBirth)) > (MONTH(GetDate())*100 + DAY(GetDate()))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)> 80
 AND (DATEDIFF(yy,DateOfBirth,GetDate()) - CASE WHEN((MONTH(DateOfBirth)*100 + DAY(C.DateOfBirth)) > (MONTH(GetDate())*100 + DAY(GetDate()))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <100
AND C.[Status] = 0 AND  S.SchemeID = 3 AND EventDate > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) order by C.clientid
```